# dockerfile tar can not read:Is a directory

Tags: tar, docker

These days, I made a dockerfile. The command is :

[image]

Then built the dockerfile, it showed :

```
tar (child): nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/src/ &&  tar zxvf nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Then I guessed that it maybe had been made the workfile in docker container. Then I used the command:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

to delete the containers, and I also deleted the images which is not succeed to create. Then I also built the dockerfile, but it also showed this questions. I don't know how to deal with it.

Finally, someone guess that it maybe created the workfile of nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz in host, but I don't know what's mean.

Thank you. Please forgive my poor Chinese English.

Comment: Please avoid using images when text will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use COPY instead of ADD. [Check this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Check the **ADD** and **COPY** documentations for an exhaustive description of their behaviours. ADD and COPY are functionally similar, generally speaking, COPY is preferred. That’s because it’s more transparent than ADD. COPY only supports the basic copying of local files into the container, while ADD has some features that are not immediately obvious.

- ADD allows  to be an URL
- If the  parameter of ADD is an    archive in a recognised compression format, it will be unpacked

Comment: Thank you for help. to use COPY instead of ADD ,have solved this question.